# What is an example of a steerable state that does not violate a Bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I understand that if a state violates Bell's inequality, it must be steerable. The relationship goes like this:
$$\text{violates Bell's inequality} \Longrightarrow \text{steerable} \Longrightarrow \text{entangled}.$$
For example, one of the Bell states $|\Phi^+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$ violates Bell's inequality and hence it is steerable. What would be an example of a state that is steerable, but does not violate Bell's inequality?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch $\rho$ Bell nonlocal implies $\rho$ steerable. I think the OP is just asking for an example of a steerable state that is *not* Bell nonlocal. Isn't that what is shown e.g. in Wiseman et al. (https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.140402)?

Comment: @glS Fair point, I got things mixed up.  If I understand the abstract correctly the example should then be some Werner or isotropic state.